# Phoenix-Spark-5.0.0-HBase-2.0 compatibility with scala 2.12

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am using Phoenix Spark 5.0.0-HBase-2.0 with an environment that provides scala 2.12
the issue is the method

```
public String[] getFieldArray(boolean skipNormalizingIdentifier, Dataset<Row> data)
```

raise exception:

```
User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions.getFieldArray(DataFrameFunctions.scala:76)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions.saveToPhoenix(DataFrameFunctions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions.saveToPhoenix(DataFrameFunctions.scala:28)
```

the method signature `refArrayOps` is for scala 2.11 and I don't find any update for Phoenix Spark from apache to support scala 2.12

please help :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops